# How to get last N documents from nested array in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

Initial "**chat**" document. Messages stored in "**messages**" array:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("65d64029a16e5d5a9d00f1e6"),
"name" : "Untitled chat",
"messages" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("65dfbba726752480ef0c4167"),
        "text" : "message 1"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("65dfbba726752480ef0c4167"),
        "text" : "message 2"
    }
 ]}
```

Im trying to get **last N messages** from this array.
I also want to apply **limit** and **skip** options.

Initially i used separate collection for messages. And my query was:

```
$cursor = $DB->messages->find(
    ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($cid)],
    ['sort' => ['_id' => -1], 'limit' => $limit, 'skip' => $skip]
  );
```

After several attempts using different variations of aggregate() and find(), I still haven't found a solution.

Language - PHP. MongoDB driver + MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: Have you checked out [$slice](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)?

Comment: @ray Thank you! Haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to [@ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14732669/ray)
Solution is:

```
  $cursor = $DB->chats->findOne(
    ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($cid)],
    [
        'projection' => ['messages' => ['slice' => [ -$limit - $skip, $limit]]],
        'sort' => ['messages._id' => -1]
    ]
);
```